# Reading a line of chars one word at a time

Tags: c, file-io

I'm new to C and I see plenty of example of reading a file one word at a time but I'm trying to make a function that is given a line of text(actually a list of filenames) and it needs to read a word(filename) at a time.

Eg. I call the function, words("file1.c file2.c file3.txt");

And the function needs to read each word(filename) and put it through another function.

So far I've got:

```
void words(char* line) {

    char buf[100];

    while (!feof(line)) {
        fscanf(line,"%s",buf);

        printf("current word %s \n", buf);  
    }
}
```

But this won't compile. I get "passing argument 1 of ‘feof’ from incompatible pointer type"

*edit* So this is the code I've come up with. It seems to work fine if I called it with words("test1 test2 test3 test4 ");  but if the last character is not a space then it has an error in the out put. eg ("test1 test2 test3 test4");

```
char buf[100];
int word_length = 0;
int n;

while((sscanf(line + word_length,"%s",buf, &n)) == 1) {
    printf("current word %s \n", buf);  
    word_length = word_length + strlen(buf) + 1;
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The `fscanf` and `feof` functions work on files.

The corresponding function for strings is `sscanf`.

The return value from `sscanf` can be used to check whether you managed to scan anything from the string and how far into the string you should look for the next word.

**Edit:**

Good effort. There are two problems left. First, if there are multiple spaces between words your code will fail. Also, the `+ 1` will move you past the null terminator if there is no space after the last word.

The second problem can be solved by not adding a +1. That means that the next item will be scanned right after the previous one ends. This is not a problem because `scanf` will skip initial whitespace.

The problem with multiple spaces can be solved by finding how far into the string the next token starts using `strstr`.

Because `strstr` returns a pointer I switched to using a pointer instead of an index to keep track of progress through the string.

```
char *ptr = line;

while((sscanf(ptr,"%s",buf)) == 1) {
    printf("current word %s \n", buf);
    ptr = strstr(ptr, buf);  // Find where the current word starts.
    ptr += strlen(buf); // Skip past the current word.
}
```

Comment: I've redone my code using sscanf and it seems to work for some strings and not others. any idea? I've edited my original post with new code.